# Runtime Erro "9" Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

so this code was made in excel 2013 and the workstations I have to use it on operate with 2003. In 2013 it works just fine, when it's in 2003 it returns "Runtime error "9" Subscript out of range". If someone could help me figure this out I would appreciate it.  It appears the issue is with this bit of data

> `Set wsSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")`

```
 With wsSheet
     Set rnData = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
 End With"
```

Once again thank you for the help.

```
`Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
 Dim rnData As Range
 Dim vaData As Variant
 Dim ncData As New VBA.Collection
 Dim lnCount As Long
 Dim vaItem As Variant

 Set wsSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

 With wsSheet
     Set rnData = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
 End With

 vaData = rnData.Value

 On Error Resume Next
     For lnCount = 1 To UBound(vaData)
     ncData.Add vaData(lnCount, 1), CStr(vaData(lnCount, 1))
 Next lnCount
 On Error GoTo 0

 With ComboBox1
     .Clear
     For Each vaItem In ncData
         .AddItem ncData(vaItem)
     Next vaItem
 End With
 End Sub

 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim c As Range
 With Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
     Set c = .Find(ComboBox2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
     c.Activate
     ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
     Sheets("Sheet2").Select
     RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
     Range("a" & RowCount + 1).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
 End With
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Range("a1").Select
 Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim cell As Range
Me.ComboBox2.Clear
For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
 If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox1 Then
     Me.ComboBox2.AddItem (cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
 End If
Next cell
Me.ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0

End Sub`
```

Comment: If you get an error on that line then the sheet name is incorrect, or the wrong workbook is active.

Comment: Is that 2003 Excel a localised version perchance?

Comment: Thanks Rory and Sun, Changed the sheet name to the actual sheet name and added the two dots and that problem is now resolved...Now onto the Compile error I am getting but I will try to figure it out before putting it on here. Thank you for the help, I'm still learning.

Comment: LocEngineer, Yes this is a localized version.

Comment: Then the sheet name is no longer "Sheet1" but "Tabelle1" or "Tableau1" or something like that. Try this instead: `Set wsSheet = Worksheets(1)`. By using the index instead of the name you should be able to avoid such problems. Also: see @Sun 's answer below regarding the dots. Your `Range`s must be qualified.

Comment: Woops, I did say I was learning right? LocEngineer, this is in fact not a localized version (had a different idea of what localized meant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be this typo (you are missing the dots before the two ranges):

```
 With wsSheet
     Set rnData = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
 End With
```

And as rory pointed out in the comments above, check if you are addressing the correct workbook. Maybe add this to be safe:

```
 Set wsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: Thank you, your feed back and Rory's both helped us make some forward progress.